# Python setup.py script isn't installing modules correctly

Tags: python, setup.py

Repo location: https://github.com/willkara/SakaiPy

So I have this python modudle I'm creating. It currently has this structure:

```
SakaiPy
├── SakaiPy
│   ├── __init__.py #1
│   └── RequestGenerator.py
├── SakaiTools
    ├── __init__.py #2
    ├── Assignment.py
    ├── Announcement.py
    └── ...etc.py
└── setup.py
```

**init**.py #1 looks like:

```
__all__=['SakaiTools']
from SakaiTools import *
```

**init**.py #2 is empty

My setup.py looks like:

```
  version='1.0',
  description='Python interface to the Sakai RESTful API\'s',
  license='MIT',
  author='William Karavites',
  author_email='wkaravites@gmail.com',
  url='https://github.com/willkara/SakaiPy',
  packages=['SakaiPy','SakaiPy/SakaiTools'],
  requires={
            "mechanize",
            "cookielib",
            "requests",
            "simplejson"}
 )
```

My problem is that the module seems to be building incorrectly.

When I try and use the module like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from SakaiPy import *

print "hello"

authInfo={}
authInfo['baseURL'] =""
authInfo['loginURL']=""
authInfo['username']=""
authInfo['password']=""

rq = RequestGenerator.RequestGenerator(authInfo)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../sakaiTest.py", line 14, in <module>
    rq = RequestGenerator.RequestGenerator(authInfo)
NameError: name 'RequestGenerator' is not defined
```

My guess is that my setup.py and **init**.py scripts are setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to change your directory stucture, as right now you technically have two Python modules and you are giving `setuptools` an incorrect package path. In order to get the path you are looking for, you are going to need to nest the `SakaiTools` directory within the `SakaiPy` directory. With this, you should be able to have the import you are looking for, and you can import `SakaiTools` as `SakiPy.SakaiTools` like you appear to be try to do.

```
SakaiPy
├── SakaiPy
│   ├── __init__.py # make this blank
│   ├── RequestGenerator.py
│   └── SakaiTools
│       ├── __init__.py # keep it blank
│       ├── Assignment.py
│       ├── Announcement.py
│       └── ...etc.py
└── setup.py
```

This will give you a single module with `SakaiTools` as a submodule, which sounds like what you are looking for. You are going to need to remve you `SakaiTools` imports from the first `__init__.py`, as you will be able to access those imports just fine with this setup.

---

If you are looking to keep the two different modules, you are going to need to tell `setuptools` that you have two different modules.

```
version='1.0',
description='Python interface to the Sakai RESTful API\'s',
license='MIT',
author='William Karavites',
author_email='wkaravites@gmail.com',
url='https://github.com/willkara/SakaiPy',
packages=['SakaiPy','SakaiTools'],
requires=(
    "mechanize",
    "cookielib",
    "requests",
    "simplejson",
)
```

Comment: I want SakaiPy to be the parent module with RequestGenerator available there and all of the 'tools' available under SakaiTools. So I could say from SakaiPy import RequestGenerator or from SakaiPy import SakaiTools.

Comment: @Sempus I fixed the answer to match what you are actually looking for

Comment: Damn, can't seem to get it to work. Could you take a look @ the repo for me? I changed the directory strucuture to what I'd want it to be.

Comment: @Sempus I think part of this is because you can't star-import modules, only classes and functions. I'd honestly recommend avoiding star imports for this reason, as you'd be better off using `from SakaiPy import RequestGenerator` which is more clear

Comment: I just used that and it looks like it worked! ...kinda. Now it looks like the code is timing out which looks like more of a error on the code end. Thanks!